# How can I find a string in SQL that could appear in different locations where its meaning is changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have become rather stumped trying to figure out how to look for a string within another string, where its meaning could be changed depending on characters that either preceded or succeed it.

I have an options list provided that is in a delimited string and depending on what options are provided depends on what data is applicable.

So I have a list that comes through that has the following:

```
A1|B2|C3|D4|E5|F6
```

From there I then need to filter another data set which uses a combination of `+`, `-`, `()` and `/` to determine what options are applicable.

So for example I may have the following:

`+A1-(C3/D4)` : This is only applicable if `A1` is present and `C3` or `D4` are not
`+(A1/B2)` : This is only applicable if `A1` or `B1` are present

The issue I have found myself in is that this can get rather confusing as required or not required may not be directly preceded by a `+` or `-`.

So for example I could have the following:

```
-A1+(B2/C3/D4)/-E5+(F6/G7/H8)
```

Which translates to:

```
Must not have A1 but have either B2, C3 or D4
```

OR

```
Must not have E5 but have either F6, G7 or H8
```

Basically I need to see if the options are either preceded by a `+` directly or within a set of `()` like `+()`, then also see if the reverse is true (so preceded by a `-` or in a `-()`).

I was thinking about using a block of LIKE statements  like below.

```
SET @option = 'E5'

SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE (
        options LIKE '%+' + @option + '%'
        OR options LIKE '%+(%' + @option + '%)%'
        )
    AND (
        options NOT LIKE '%-' + @option + '%'
        OR options LIKE '%-(%' + @option + '%)%'
        )
```

However, I am concerned that in certain circumstances this may fail.

For example, if the options list on the data row was:

```
+A1-(B2/C3/D4)/-E5+(F6/G7)
```

As *technically* `F6` sits in `-(%F6%)` so it would not apply, even though it should.

I hope this makes sense. I am sure it is very simple but at the moment it has got me a little stumped as I am not overly familiar with regex.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a possibility for options like F7, F72 and AF7 at the same time? Or are they limited to one letter and one number?

Comment: It may be possible to write a _generic_ query (though I currently don't see how you could make sure that it would work for all possible scenarios). I would approach this differently, meaning write a rater simple stored procedure that would parse the string and trigger the correct sub-process (here I'm assuming that the logic is always LTR).

Comment: The root of the problem is storing these delimited strings. I have a gut feeling you are working with an EAV design which is getting complicated to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the responses so far. Sadly I have no control of the data as it is sent to me in the format given. There are other options available as well, for the example I split it down to 2 characters but they can be between 3 and 4 characters of either numbers or letters in any order. It is certainly the catch all that is causing the issues. I assume there must be a way around it. It is always LTR as well and the different blocks are always separated by a /. However that could be a block in a sublist, identified by ().